# How do I distribute whitespace equally between columns in a HTML table?

Tags: css, html-table

I have a HTML table that has a fixed width of 1000 px (say), which is much greater than needed to accommodate the text in the table. It looks like:

[image]
The "Salary" column has right-aligned text, while the other columns have left-aligned text. (I've added the pink and green backgrounds so that you can see how it's getting laid out. It's not part of the actual table.)

How do I ask it to put equal whitespace between the columns? In other words, in the following screenshot:

[image]

I've added two green rectangles to illustrate the whitespace between the columns (more precisely, between the last visible pixel in one column to the first visible pixel in the next). I want these two green rectangles to be of the same *width*. How do I do that? Is it even possible in HTML?

Keep in mind that the text is dynamic — we don't know ahead of time what text will appear in each column, or how wide it will be.

Here's the code I used:

```html
<table style="width:1000px;">
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF">Name</th>
    <th style="text-align:right;">Salary</th>
    <th style="text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF">Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF">Kartick</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">10</td>
    <td style="text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF">Director of Nothing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF">Neha</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">200</td>
    <td style="text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF">Minister of Awesome</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF">Vijay</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">3000</td>
    <td style="text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF">VP of Buzzwords</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PS: Please ignore the use of inline styles. This is throwaway code.

Comment: There is no column **between** the numbers and the 'Title' columns so it's not clear what you are trying to do - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/u1eh5nqm/3/

Comment: The browser distributes remaining space among columns "proportionally" instead of evenly, depending on the width of text. To achieve the desired result you must use 5 columns instead of 3.

Comment: Salman, what do I do with the other two columns? Paulie, I don't need a column between the salary and title columns. Why do I need it? I just want a table with three columns. What I'm trying to do is spelt out in the question -- equal whitespace (green rectangles) between the columns.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways of doing this. You can apply a fixed width to the `td` element, however this requires you to know how many columns there are.

The second way is to apply `table-layout: fixed` to the `table` element.

http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/gbzgNQ

To get equal whitespace, you will have to set explicit widths on the first two columns, and padding-left on the last column.

http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/ByxpXb

Comment: Alex, I can't apply a fixed width to the td, because it depends on the text. And for that reason, I can't use table-layout: fixed, either, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Then I am not sure how to do it, unless you add another column between salary and title, and apply a width to that.

Comment: But what width do I apply to that? It depends on the text, and I don't know what text will be there.

Comment: I guess then the only way forward would be JavaScript. Calculate the width of the text fields, and set the width accordingly. There is no way CSS knows what content is contained in anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this: **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hhvtr60t/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
th, td{
    width:333px; /* specify in px or % as per your requirement */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table> <!-- removed Width from table tag -->
<tr>
<th style="text-align:left; ">Name</th>
<th style="text-align:right;">Salary</th>
<th style="text-align:left;">Title</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left; ">Kartick</td>
<td style="text-align:right;">10</td>
<td style="text-align:left; ">Director of Nothing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left; ">Neha</td>
<td style="text-align:right;">200</td>
<td style="text-align:left; ">Minister of Awesome</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left; ">Vijay</td>
<td style="text-align:right;">3000</td>
<td style="text-align:left; ">VP of Buzzwords</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But the columns are not of the same width. In fact, I don't know the width of the text -- it's dynamic.

Comment: But it still doesn't the same amount of whitespace between the text in the columns.